# Distribution of $X + 2Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d Poisson

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

> Use MGFs to determine whether $X + 2Y$ is Poisson, for $X, Y$ i.i.d. $\sim\mathcal P(\lambda)$.

So, I know that the MGF of $X+Y$ is the product of the two respective MGFs. Thus, we get:
$ X+2y = X + Y + Y$, which we can then multiply the MGF of $X * Y * Y$, which = $e^{3λ(e^t -1)}$. However, I don't think I did this calculation right. Anyone help me?

Comment: What I'm wondering, though, is if I shoul'dve done e^(λ*(e^t - 1)) * 2 e^(λ*(e^t - 1))?

Comment: The MGF for a sum of *independent* random variables equals the product of the MGF for the variables.  However, $Y$ is not independent from $Y$ not independent, so the MGF for $2Y$ is *not* the square of the MGF for $Y$.

Comment: What in the world do you mean by $X*Y*Y$? If the asterisk represents multiplication, it's wrong: one _adds_ the random variables, and multiplication would be done with the MGFs, not with $X$ and $Y$. If it represents convolution, it's wrong, since convolution would be done with the PMFs, not with $X$ and $Y.$ And you would multiply the MGFs if the random variables are independent, and these are not independent. Also, one can write $3\cdot5$ or $3\times5.$ You're not restricted to characters that are on the keyboard, so you don't need to resort to an asterisk for multiplication. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so are $X$ and $2Y$. The MGF of $X+2Y$ evaluated at $t$ is $$\exp(\lambda(e^{t}-1))\exp(\lambda(e^{2t}-1)) = \exp(\lambda(e^{2t}+e^{t}-2))$$

This is not the MGF of any Poisson distributed random variable, so $X+2Y$ is not Poisson.

To prove that $\exp(\lambda(e^{2t}+e^{t}-2))$ is not the MGF of a Poisson variable, not that it's asymptotically $\displaystyle \sim e^{\lambda e^{2t}}$ while the MGF of a Poisson variable would be $\displaystyle\sim e^{\beta e^{t}}$ (which is a contradiction, except when $\lambda=0$, but this is irrelevant).

Comment: So, this makes somewhat sense... but I'm wondering how to do this with MGFs instead. Are my calculations wrong?

Comment: @JohnB. you can make the same case with MGF's. $$\exp(\lambda(e^{t}-1))\exp(\lambda(e^{2t}-1)) = \exp(\lambda(e^{2t}+e^{t}-2))$$ There's still a proof missing that the LHS cannot be the MGF of a Poisson variable. But that shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: @JohnB. you made a mistake after you wrote $X+2Y = X + Y + Y$. $Y$ is not independent from itself, so you cannot multiply all the MGF together.

Comment: Understood. Is the "proof" that's missing simply that the MGF you get from multiplying the two of them isn't equivalent to the MGF of a Poisson R.V.?

Comment: @JohnB. "isn't equivalent" is not a proof. You need a real argument, see for example what I wrote about the asymptotics.